# Experience Profile Error : Sitecore.XConnect.XdbSearchUnavailableException

Tags: experience-profile

i'm using sitecore 9.0.1, i'm trying to view custom interactions in the Experience Profile however when i open Experience profile i get no contacts (neither logged in nor anonymous contacts).

[image]
After checking my cm logs i found the following exception:

> Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbSearchUnavailableException
>   Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
>   Source: Sitecore.XConnect.Client
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.SearchWebApiClient.d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

and the xconnect logs contains the following [ERROR]:

> 2018-11-27 14:20:22.589 +04:00 [Error] Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.XdbSearchOperation`1[Sitecore.XConnect.Contact]: System.TimeoutException: A wait for data to be indexed has been timed out.
>   2018-11-27 14:20:22.589 +04:00 [Error] ["XdbContextLoggingPlugin"] XdbContext Batch Execution Exception
>   System.TimeoutException: A wait for data to be indexed has been timed out.

Any idea what might be causing this error??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-client-api/batch-indexing.html

> xConnect increments a sync token in the storage layer each time a batch is submitted to xConnect. If the client’s SyncToken property is set when a search is performed, results will only be returned when indexing has caught up to **at least that number**.

The xConnect service ensures that data is indexed by the [xConnect Indexer Service](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-search-indexer/configuration.html) at least up to the SyncToken that is passed by the xConnect client. If the data is not yet indexed, the service waits for a certain period of time (30 seconds by default).

If after the 30 seconds the data is not yet in the search index, it throws `System.TimeoutException: A wait for data to be indexed has been timed out.` This is what you see in the logs.

Most likely the xConnect Indexer Service is stopped, slow or overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

@Roman Klimenko's answer did not work for me, but pointed me in the right direction.

My Indexer Service was running fine, sort of. The logs showed a lot of thrown exceptions all over the place. It turns out my Solr service itself had entered a paused state so it was Solr rejecting all connections to it.

In my scenario, it was down because of a change in the Java path for the Environment Variable due to a recent Java update, but in general if Solr is down the search against the collection will throw a similar exception.