Experience Profile Page throws an error and does not load any data
I shifted the root folder of the XConnect Site from one server to a different server and made the necessary configuration changes. I checked Solr and Experience Analytics, which work perfectly.
However, the Experience Profile is still not loading any data.
I'm having trouble comprehending, how this is impacting the Experience profile.
A screenshot of the same is attached below:

In the logs, I found the below mentioned exceptions:-
[Error] Exception System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Sitecore.XConnect.XdbSearchUnavailableException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException: A task was canceled. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<SendAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
        
[Error] Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.AddContactOperation: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'AllowedTypesValidatorSerializationBinder' threw an exception. ---> System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Multiple custom attributes of the same type found.


Does every other tool which uses xConnect work normally? Experience Analytics? Launchpad graphs? Path Analyzer?

Yes, I have checked Experience Analytics is working and Launchpad graphs are also working fine.

Have you created a custom collection model? If so are they correctly deployed to collection/search and indexer? https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/deploy-a-custom-model.html

Any errors showing in logs of those three locations?

I found this Exception in xconnect logs:
ERROR Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.XdbSearchOperation1[Sitecore.XConnect.Contact]: Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Failures.DataProviderException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Did you check this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15185/experience-profile-error-sitecore-xconnect-xdbsearchunavailableexception ?

@GauravAgarwal Yes, I have checked the link provided by you. But in my case index worker service is running fine.

Based on the System.OutofMemoryException  you have added into the comments, I would suggest the server hosting your XConnect instances is perhaps under resourced.
What is your setup? What specification is the VM? How many services are on the server in question? Does it also contain processing instance? Is it load balanced? If so how many instances? These types of instances ofter plac large volumes of data into RAM, so if not sufficient you will see this type exceptions.
The best solution would be to try increasing specification. But if this is not possible, try switching of any less essential services and recycling XConnect instances to see if it resolves the problem.
